# Is it possible to merge a table in MSSQL with a view based on the same table?

Tags: sql-server, view, merge

Something like this

```
create view V1 as 
select * from (T1 union T2) join T3 where "some condition on T3"

Then later in the process:
merge T2 using V1 
when not matched by Target then insert
when not matched by Source then delete
```

Is MS SQL server smart enough to handle this?

Comment: *"Is MS SQL server smart enough to handle this?"* It's not valid syntax. You can't perform a DML statement inside a `VIEW`.

Comment: Of course the merge is not inside the view. Just the automatic format put it right under the view definition. Two steps - 1)create view, 2)use the view in merge

Comment: @Larnu Was it a joke? Sorry, not sure...

Comment: Was what a joke, @Qlk ?

Comment: No, I'm not joking, @Qlk ; you **cannot** perform a DML statement inside a `VIEW`. `MERGE` is a DML statement.

Comment: @Larnu  -Sorry, I must be missing something or don't understand you. The invalid syntax you are mentioning concerns my question "Is MSSQL smart enough to handle this?" ? What kind of syntax concerning my question? Do you mean syntax of the question in English language?

Comment: @Qlk Yes you can use a view as the merge source. [Example on DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=304f6b1179b99e155c71228b3cbab4e9).

Comment: Thanks @GarethD, exactly this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to use a view (which references the target table) in a merge statement:

```
create table t1
(
    id int,
    colA int
)
go

create table t2
(
    id int,
    colB int
)
go

create view dbo.testview
as
select id, colB
from t2
except
select id, colA
from t1
go


insert into t2(id, colB) values (1, 2)
go

--populate t1 with the values of t2 (that do not exist yet in t1)
merge t1 as t
using testview as s on t.colA = s.colB
when not matched by target then 
insert(id, colA)
values(id, colB);
go
select *
from t2;
select *
from t1;
go

insert into t2(id, colB) values (1, 2)

merge t1 as t
using testview as s on t.colA = s.colB
when not matched by target then 
insert(id, colA)
values(id, colB);
go

select *
from t2;
select *
from t1;
go

drop view testview;
drop table t1;
drop table t2;
go
```